# Count rows with multiple criteria in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, datetime

I have a pandas dataframe with "user_ID", "datetime" and "action_type" columns like it is shown below and I want to get the last column (the last column = desired output) by performing some calculations:

```py
data = {'user_id': list('ddabdacddaaa'), 
            'datetime':pd.date_range("20201001", periods=12, freq='H'), 
            'action_type':list('XXXWZWKOOXWX'), 
            'as_if_X_calculated':list('121021022223')
           }
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df
```

```
    user_id datetime    action_type as_if_X_calculated
0   d   2020-10-01 00:00:00 X   1
1   d   2020-10-01 01:00:00 X   2
2   a   2020-10-01 02:00:00 X   1
3   b   2020-10-01 03:00:00 W   0
4   d   2020-10-01 04:00:00 Z   2
5   a   2020-10-01 05:00:00 W   1
6   c   2020-10-01 06:00:00 K   0
7   d   2020-10-01 07:00:00 O   2
8   d   2020-10-01 08:00:00 O   2
9   a   2020-10-01 09:00:00 X   2
10  a   2020-10-01 10:00:00 W   2
11  a   2020-10-01 11:00:00 X   3
```

So the last column shows how many times the user has performed an action X at the time of the current record. If we see a user "a", his results will be like 1-1-2-2-3 in chronological order. So how can I calculate the number of action X for the given user that happened at the time of the record or earlier?

P.S. In Excel it would look like `=countifs(A:A; A2; B:B; "<="&B2; C:C; "X")` (Column A = "user_id")

Comment: I showed it in the last column. As input, I have 4 first columns (without index col) and the 5th col is the desired output

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your dataframe is sorted by `datetime` you can create a temporary column for the condition on `action_type` and use [`pd.expanding`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.expanding.html)

```
df.sort_values('datetime', inplace=True)
df['dummy'] = df.action_type == 'X'
df['X_calculated'] = (df.groupby('user_id')['dummy']
                      .expanding().sum()
                      .reset_index(level=0, drop=True)
                      .astype('int'))
df.sort_index(inplace=True)
print(df.drop('dummy', 1))
assert df.as_if_X_calculated.astype('int').equals(df.X_calculated), 'X_calculated is not equal'
```

Out:

```
   user_id            datetime action_type as_if_X_calculated  X_calculated
0        d 2020-10-01 00:00:00           X                  1             1
1        d 2020-10-01 01:00:00           X                  2             2
2        a 2020-10-01 02:00:00           X                  1             1
3        b 2020-10-01 03:00:00           W                  0             0
4        d 2020-10-01 04:00:00           Z                  2             2
5        a 2020-10-01 05:00:00           W                  1             1
6        c 2020-10-01 06:00:00           K                  0             0
7        d 2020-10-01 07:00:00           O                  2             2
8        d 2020-10-01 08:00:00           O                  2             2
9        a 2020-10-01 09:00:00           X                  2             2
10       a 2020-10-01 10:00:00           W                  2             2
11       a 2020-10-01 11:00:00           X                  3             3
```

Comment: In the example above the dataframe is sorted by ```datetime```, but in fact it is not

Comment: Then sort by `datetime` before and by the index after the operations. I updated my answer, even so it does nothing in your example data.

Comment: Thank you!
Usually, I deal with large sets of data, so does this sorting step can be omitted in order to facilitate the data processing? (in this case the script will a bit differ)